# Duration of jQuery events not equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two lines of code firing on the click of a div. They do what I want them to, but it seems that the timing of them is out of sync. These are the two lines.

```
$('#tourPage').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
$('#navigationRight').animate({marginLeft: '-1240px'}, 500);
```

I have the duration of both of them set to 500, but they don't move together. There seems to be some sort of separation or something between them. I haven't had this trouble before. I used this and it works just fine.

```
$('#aboutPage').animate({width: 'hide'}, 500);
$("#navigationLeft").animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
```

Those two elements do move together when clicked.

Any ideas why time is different in the first case?

Thanks

Comment: The animate function runs in async mode.... and you have 2 different animations running so there could be some slight sync issues...

Comment: It is best not to rely on such details and effects looking entirely equal on all browsers and systems. You can consider it an approximation. As such you might as well use an interval before you fire the event which came too early. But that'd be real dirty, too.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. If there's a way to use animate to slide from right to left, I figure that would fix it. But I don't know how to reverse that second code snippet to show/hide the other direction.

Comment: Yeah, i've been trying to set a delay on the second one to time it but that's nearly impossible lol

Comment: use `complete` callback to start the reverse